# SQL Server 2008 vs 2008 R2 for production

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a SQL 2008 R2 Express edition. Now that its time to deploy, I need the Standard edition sql server. The database is simple with a million records of addresses which could be queried using google maps with a zip code. Also, it will be storing account information like username and password which are limited(maybe 30-40 accounts). It will be hosted in one server only  and once accessible using those account information(not a public web site). I am planning to setup SQL Server authentication. Can any one tell me if 2008 should be enough for my purpose or do I need 2008 R2 for some specific reason? Also 2008 R2 is really expensive compare to 2008. 5 CAL license is enough for me as I will be the only one handling the database. Since, this is my first production deployment, I am not sure what to chose.
Please let me know.

Comment: sql server's licensing requires a license for EVERY user of the db, even if that user is only connecting via your app. If this DB is going to be driving a website, you'd need a license for every possible user of your site.

Comment: why do you exactly need the standard edition? i am asking because express edition **can be used for commercial purposes**. If you can live with the limitations, it seems to be ok.

Comment: Well for one you won't be able to restore your 2008 R2 database to 2008. You should be developing and deploying on the same version, or going up, but going down just doesn't work.

Comment: That's what I am not getting about CAL VS Core.
I have a table where I will have username and password stored.
In the UI of the application, they will enter that information and I will match if it exists in the table. If its there, he can use the site and do query on addresses. So, if I have 10 user/pwd records in the database, then my 5 CAL license won't work? I was getting a lot of out of memory exception when I was importing xml and csv files to the database. I have thousands of those to import to the address table.

Comment: Out of memory exceptions have nothing to do with licensing issues. That said, we can't really give licensing / legal advice here. You need to contact your reseller or Microsoft licensing rep (e.g. where you bought your CAL licenses) and describe your exact environment and user base. They will tell you if CAL will work (I somehow doubt it will, since essentially, if it's a web site, it can't use CAL - this doesn't have anything to do with users you set up *inside your database/application*).

Comment: I just checked my database size, it is 2 GB(8GB) left for express edition limitation. I also found that it only uses 1 core and 1 GB of RAM.
Considering, 20 users max at a time, any chances for sql server express edition to require more processor or more ram?
@AaronBertrand Thank You for your suggestion. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I have no idea what your workload is like, so no, sorry, impossible for me to even venture a guess what your CPU/memory requirements are going to be like

Comment: Could you please tell me what would be considered in the workload?

Comment: That's like asking what's in traffic. No idea. Major expressway? Dirt road? Something in between? Only you know what your workload is/will be. This is basically all of the activity that will happen on your server, plus generous overestimates for peak volume.

Comment: Ok Thanks.One guy is trying to sell me SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition and says it includes the 1 + 4 server instances license.
He says that it is MSDN software and should work fine and its based on core.
I dont know if MSDN is different than what we find in retail?
Can we use MSDN version for my public application and not face any issues from Microsoft license check?